# Custom domains created in one owner account not visible on other owner accounts on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

In one of my app engine projects,  I'm using Custom Domains mapping which I created whilst logged into one of the owner accounts.

However, when I login to other owner accounts for the same project,  I can no longer see the custom domains which I setup earlier

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you setup a Custom Domain on account A. Logged into account B and it is not visible in the Developer console. If so then this is something Google is already working on.

As a workaround you can add account B in the webmaster tools to have it visible as well.